# Reversed order of constructor calls by inheriting a constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I have a class that first needs to call the derived class constructor before it calls the base constructor. I know that by the following code the base constructor will be called first:

```
public class A {

    protected A () {
        //do something
    }

}

public class B : A {

    public B () : base() {
        //do something else
    }

}
```

Is their a way to reverse that order, or a workaround for it? One of the possible solutions in which we create an additional protected method in the base-class like doConstructor() and call it in the derived constructor after the first task isn't possible with readonly fields because the compiler will not accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to accomplish this. In the past, I've encountered this situation too and used an `Initialize` method to work around it.

```
public class A
{
    protected A()
    {
        // Do pre-initialization here still.

        Initialize();
    }

    protected virtual Initialize()
    {
        // Do all post-derived-class initialization here.
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override Initialize()
    {
        // Do initialization between pre- and post- initialization here.

        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

As long as you follow the guidelines of pre-, post-, and normal initialization here, it could be reasonably safe and within good practice.

Comment: It looks like you are reading the code off my screen ;o) We should be aware though that calling virtual members from constructors are usually advised against.

Comment: Calling virtual methods in the base-constructor (`A`) is a bit dangerous; `B`'s override is now running **before** `B`'s constructor, which could lead to problems with uninitialized fields. I would generally advise caution here, or better: a **post**-ctor `Initialize` step.

Comment: @Fredrik: Hehe, yeah. I'm not surprised this is the method other people use too. I wasn't aware that calling virtual members from constructors is advised against - any reason in particular? Anyway, I think it's quite safe in this case.

Comment: @Marc: Good point. I shall clarify the code a bit to show how this issue can be (at least partially removed).

Comment: @Fredrik... It's generally considered a bad idea because it will always call the derived method... In other words, deriving from a base class changes the execution of the base class itself... In this case that's okay, but in general changing the behaviour of a separate class like that is likely to break any dependent code that was relying on the old behaviour.

Comment: @MarcGravell: The whole *point* of calling the virtual method is to allow the derived class to execute code before calling upon parts of the base-class initialization. Any part of derived-class initialization which must happen after base-class initialization can go after the `base.Initialize()` call. Incidentally, one nice thing about this pattern is that if the base class implements `IDisposable`, it can wrap the `Initialize` call in `bool ok=false; try {Initialize(); ok=true;} finally {if (!ok) Dispose(); } and its resources won't leak even if a derived-class `Initialize()` throws.